# Show that the space $\imath ^{p}$ of sequences is complete

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

> Question: Show that $\imath ^{p}$ is complete

On the space of sequence $\imath , for 1\leq p<\infty
\left \| x \right \|_{p}:=\left ( \sum_{I=1}^{\infty} \left \| x_{i} \right \|^{p}\right )^{\frac{1}{p}}$

and
$\imath ^{p}:=\left \{ x \in \imath : \left \| x \right \|_{p}<\infty \right \}$ is a normed space.

I think what I do need to show is that every Cauchy sequence function in $\imath ^{p}$ converges.

However, I am facing some issues getting the ball rolling.

Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: suppose you have a Cauchy sequence $(x^n)$ in $\iota^p$. Can you think of a candidate for its limit $x$? Can you prove that $x \in\iota^p$? Can you prove that the sequence $(x^n)$ converges to $x$?

Comment: Would the limit of the sequence being x be a suitable candidate?@MeesdeVries

Comment: What do you mean by "the limit of the sequence"?

Comment: My reply was very sloppy. 
I meant the limit of the Cauchy sequence (x^{n}) in the space of sequence.@MeesdeVries

Comment: Well, you have to prove that such a limit exists. (Note that $x^n$ is a sequence of sequences, not a single sequence itself. For each $k$, there is a sequence $(x^k_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$.

Comment: Am I right to say that $x^{n}$ lives in a Cauchy sequence ($x_{n}$)?

Comment: I don't know what that would mean. $x^n$ is a sequence of elements of $\iota^p$, so for each $k$, the element of the sequence $x^k \in \iota^p$. That is, $x^k$ is a sequence itself.

Comment: Isn't it also a sequence of elements of $x_{n}$? That's what I understand from Wikipedia.
I'm attempting to grapple the basic since analysis is taught-right off the bat-at the more advanced level in my school.

Comment: The space of sequence is extremely elusive a concept to me. 
The sequence ($x_{n}$) are elements in a field of scalar.
If, say, $x_{1}$=1. What exactly is $x_{n=1}^{k}$ for all natural number k?
How does one even have a sequence for a point?

Comment: Let $X$ be an arbitrary set. Now what does it mean for $(x^n)$ to be a sequence of elements of $X$? It means that for each $k \in \mathbb N$, we have that $x^k \in X$. In particular $X$ can be a *set of sequences*, as it is in this case. That measn that $x^k$, which is the $k$th element of the sequence, is *itself* is a sequence.

Comment: Helps a bit but only revealed that my misunderstanding runs deep.
I'm very sure the space of sequence or the sequence space $\imath $ is the set of all sequence $\left ( x_{n} \right )n \in \mathbb{N}$
But what exactly is $\imath ^{p}$ then? Wikipedia states $\imath^{p} $ this is the sequence space. @MeesdeVries

Comment: $\iota^p$ is defined in your question. It is a subspace of $\iota$.

Comment: But $l^{p}$ is not a sequence space right?@MeesdeVries

Comment: Yes, it is. It is the space consisting of all sequences for which a particular series defined in terms of it converges.

Comment: So it is a subset of l? Shouldn't then the elements in $l^{p}$ be sequences ($x_{n}$) instead? Why is it x? It doesn't quite make any sense to me..